# Filter large collection with an efficient way

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, geolocation

I m Working on an app like uber , I have a collection of drivers , with currentPosition { latitude , longitutde }

And i want to get the drivers far by 200m , the way i did it is like this on the model :

```
driverSchema.methods.CloseDriver = function (userCurrentPosition,next) {
  try {    
    const distance = geolib.getPreciseDistance(
      userCurrentPosition,
      this.currentPosition
   );
   return distance <= 200
  } catch (error) {
      return next();
  }
}
```

and then with a post request with currentPosition of the user on it

```
     const parsedBody = Object.setPrototypeOf(req.body, {});

      if(parsedBody.hasOwnProperty("latitude") && parsedBody.hasOwnProperty("longitude")){
        const { latitude , longitude } = req.body
        const currentPosition = { latitude , longitude }
        const drivers = await Driver.find({})
        const eligibleDrivers =  drivers.filter((driver)=> driver.CloseDriver(currentPosition))
        return res.status(200).json({
          status : 200 , 
          eligibleDrivers
        });
```

if we have large array of drivers that would not be very efficient if there is another way to this?

Comment: If by "large" you mean < 1 million, then it doesn't really matter, this is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$geoNear` with `aggregate` to achieve this from your query itself & not loading all the drivers & then doing this filter in javascript

See this code

```
db.drivers.aggregate([
   {
     $geoNear: {
        near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ CurrentLongitude, CurrentLatitude ] },
        distanceField: "distance",
        maxDistance: 2,
        includeLocs: "currentPosition",
        spherical: true
     }
   }
]);
```

You'd have to store currentPosition latlang of drivers in your schema like this

```
"currentPosition": {
      "type" : "Point",
      "coordinates" : [ -73.9375, 40.8303 ]
   },
```